# How to pass a field that is an array list in a java bean, within a JasperReports?

Tags: arraylist, jasper-reports, javabeans, ireport

Could some indicate a working example or a snippet of code for `JasperReports` regarding ArrayList as a Field in a javabean datasource.

I have a List of Employees. Each *`Employee`* has a ***`name`*** field, and an array of *`Phone`* with ***`type`*** and ***`number`*** as its fields.

Do i use a subreport for `Phone`s I have not found a working example? Cant seem to compile subreport_jasper file?

Do i use a  `list` component instead...

```xml
<c:list ...>
    <datasetRun subDataset="Addresses">
        <datasetParameter name="Phone">
            <datasetParameterExpression><![CDATA[$F{Phone}]]></datasetParameterExpression>
        </datasetParameter>
    </datasetRun>
```

This does seems to work either?

Thank in advance

Comment: Did you see this [sample](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/sample.reference/datasource/index.html#javabeandatasources)? You can find samples in `$jasperreports$\demo\samples` folder in the JasperReports distribution package.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wrote [this article](http://mdahlman.wordpress.com/2012/02/03/collections-in-reports-on-mongodb/) while working with MongoDB. It deals with handling fields that are collections. It should be exactly what you need. (You can just ignore the MongoDB part.)

The key idea is that you use this to pass data to a List or Table or Subreport:

```
new net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRMapCollectionDataSource($F{PhoneArray})
```

Comment: Thanks for the response nearly got everything working, do you know how i would pass a parameter in the the subDataset....

Comment: If you right-click on your Table element, for example, you'll see the tab that let's you pass parameters to it.